# Select non duplicated records based on two columns

Tags: r, duplicates, subset

Let's suppose I have:

```
V1  V2  id
R1  R2  1
R1  R3  2
R1  R5  3
R1  R7  4
R2  R1  5
R2  R3  6
R2  R8  7
R3  R1  8
R3  R2  9
R3  R6  10
R4  R9  11
```

Code to generate dataset:

```
dat1 <- data.frame(
  V1 = c(rep("R1", 4), rep("R2", 3), rep("R3", 3), "R4"),
  V2 = c("R2", "R3", "R5", "R7", "R1", "R3", "R8", "R1", "R2", "R6", "R9"), 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

dat1$id <- 1:nrow(dat1)
```

I want to select non duplicated records based on V1 and V2 columns, 
e.g. id 1 and id 5 need to be treated as same records so id 1 should be selected. So desired outcome is:

```
V1  V2  id
R1  R2  1
R1  R3  2
R1  R5  3
R1  R7  4
R2  R3  6
R2  R8  7
R3  R6  10
R4  R9  11
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apply` `sort` with V1 and V2 then using `duplicated` find the duplicated items

```
dat1[!duplicated(t(apply(dat1[,-3],1,sort))),]
   V1 V2 id
1  R1 R2  1
2  R1 R3  2
3  R1 R5  3
4  R1 R7  4
6  R2 R3  6
7  R2 R8  7
10 R3 R6 10
11 R4 R9 11
```